# SQL syntax error using UPDATE/SET

Tags: php, mysql

The error I receive: **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'release=`2012-09-02`, platforms=`Android`, link=`play.php?game=G' at line 6**

The code:

```
$sql = "UPDATE
            GameInformation
        SET
            keyIndex=`GameTest`,
            name=`Game Test`,
            release=`2012-09-02`,
            platforms=`Android`,
            link=`play.php?game=GameTest`,
            icon=`img/thumb_gametest.png`,
            thumb=`img/thumb_mini_gametest.png`,
            swf=`swf/GameTest.swf`,
            height=`500`,
            width=`920`
        WHERE
            keyIndex=`GameTest2`";

$query = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$query) exit (mysql_error());
```

I've been trying different delimiters (braces, apostrophes, quotes) around my set vars with no avail. Is there a reserved word in here?

Update [Solved], corrected code:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE
                            `GameInformation`
                        SET
                            `keyIndex`="GameTest",
                            `name`="Game Test",
                            `release`="2012-09-02",
                            `platforms`="Android",
                            `link`="play.php?game=GameTest",
                            `icon`="img/thumb_gametest.png",
                            `thumb`="img/thumb_mini_gametest.png",
                            `swf`="swf/GameTest.swf",
                            `height`="500",
                            `width`="920"
                        WHERE
                            `keyIndex`="GameTest2"';
            $query = mysql_query($sql);
            if (!$query) exit (mysql_error());
```

Comment: have you tried escaping the `?` with `\?` ?

Comment: If you take out the release field does it run with no errors? What type is release? I'm thinking it's a date format issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use ` for table and column names and " or ' for content. RELEASE is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

```
UPDATE
            `GameInformation`
        SET
            `keyIndex`="GameTest",
            `name`="Game Test",
            `release`="2012-09-02",
            `platforms`="Android",
            `link`="play.php?game=GameTest",
            `icon`="img/thumb_gametest.png",
            `thumb`="img/thumb_mini_gametest.png",
            `swf`="swf/GameTest.swf",
            `height`="500",
            `width`="920"
        WHERE
            `keyIndex`="GameTest2"
```

Answer (score 0):

`release` is a reserved word in mysql.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html